Is it possible to convert public key to private key if anybody can decode doubling to singling?
If a point is P then,
P => Doubling operation => 2P
If anybody can reverse it, i,e
2P => Reverse Doubling => P
Will he/she be able to calculate private key from the specific public key of bitcoin? If possible, how?

Anyone can do the question's "Reverse doubling". One way is multiplying by $(n+1)/2$, where $n$ is the group order, and a known prime for standard curves. This works because $((n+1)/2);!2\equiv1\pmod n$. Draw your own conclusion about how helpful that is towards calculating private key from a public key.
